# Check exact match of string with brackets in another string Python

Tags: python

There are many answers to a similar type of question to mine, but I'm not sure why this isn't working.

I've got a very simple example of two strings, where I am checking if one is contained in another (with an exact match).

For example, suppose I've got the following:

```
import re

text = "random/path/" 
search = "test/random/path/path_with_brackets[3]/another_path"

if re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(text), search, re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
    print("text is contained in search")
else:
    print("text not contained in search")
```

As expected, the above code returns:

> text is contained in search

since an exact match of "random/path/" is found in "test/random/path/path_with_brackets[3]/another_path"

However, if I add an extra path (that contains brackets) to the text, such as:

```
import re

text = "random/path/path_with_brackets[3]" 
search = "test/random/path/path_with_brackets[3]/another_path"

if re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(text), search, re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
    print("text is contained in search")
else:
    print("text not contained in search")
```

the text is not found in search, even though it exists. The result is:

> text not contained in search

What am I doing wrong in the second example? Does the fact that "text" have brackets change anything?

Comment: Yes, brackets are the reason.  Brackets are special characters in regular expressions.  Do you even need regular expressions?  It seems like plain substring matching would be enough. `if text in search:`

Comment: You sir are indeed correct. This was so simple and I don't know why I complicated it all. Your suggestion worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "replace" to validate brackets and use * to match 0 or more repetitions.

```
import re

text = "random/path/path_with_brackets[3]"
text = text.replace('[','\[')
search = "test/random/path/path_with_brackets[3]/another_path"

if re.search(r".*{}.*".format(text), search, re.IGNORECASE) is not None:
    print("text is contained in search")
else:
    print("text not contained in search")
```

Comment: Use `re.escape` for a more thorough replacement. I posted an answer including it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use regex, you can [simply use `in`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3437059/4518341):

```
print(text in search)  # -> True
```

---

If you do need to use regex, like if the word boundaries are important, i.e. you don't want `random` to match inside `get_random` for example, then you'll need to escape the brackets since they're special; they represent a character set. E.g. `[3]` matches `3`. You can do that with [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(text))
```

But then you have another problem: `]/` isn't a word boundary, so `\b` won't match there. To fix it you can use a similar concept to `\b`:

```
r"(?:^|\W)({})(?:$|\W)".format(...)
```

These are non-capturing groups that match either the start/end of the string or a non-word character.

It also makes sense to put your desired text in a group so that you can retrieve it with `.group(1)`.